# writing postgres table records to s3 using flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-batch

If this kind of error occur while executing insert statement on flink( like trying to ingest rdbms data to s3 Inmy case I was trying to write from postgres to s3 buckte using flink)

[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@6686507b: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@43dddfdd: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]

Answer: I am providing solution which works in my case firstly check the credentials of aws that you have provided to flink to connect with s3 bucket if all the creds are correct an have all access then do aws cli setup using below commands:

pip install awscli

aws configure

aws s3 ls

May this can resolve your issue.